# WebRequest to Shoutcast throws "invalid or unrecognized response" exception

Tags: asp.net-web-api, webrequest

I'm trying to read metadata from shoutcast stream using ASP.net WebAPI, .net core 2.1. All I need is the headers and not the audio data.
I found out that Shoutcast servers 2+ give stats xml page, but for compatibility reasons, I need to work this out so I can support v1 too. The /7.html does not give the title and genre.
Following is piece of relevant code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = null;
HttpWebResponse response = null;
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(server);
request.Headers.Clear();
request.Headers.Add("GET", "/ HTTP/1.0");
// needed to receive metadata information
request.Headers.Add("Icy-MetaData", "1");
request.UserAgent = "WinampMPEG/5.09";

response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
info.Title=response.Headers["icy-name"];
info.Genre=response.Headers["icy-genre"];
```

When I run this code on IIS Express, or publish and run on IIS, I get this error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
HttpRequestException: The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response.
System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ThrowInvalidHttpResponse()

WebException: The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response.
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

I have tried WebClient and StreamReader as well but the issue seems to be consistent.
However I tried the same code in Console Application and it seems to work just fine.

How can I get this to work through a WebAPI on IIS?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. I used HttpClient and PostAsync to fix the issue.

It is to note that I initially tried my code with dot net framework rather than dot net core and it was working fine, so I think HttpWebResponse is not compatible with dot net core in some cases.
Have a look on below links, if using HttpClient still does not fix your issue. I hope it helps.
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/14897

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/30040